# website in iis 7 not displaying to browser

Tags: html, iis

I have a website written in HTML5 and have already added it to iis7. I checked to make sure that the path was correct, and both the path and the authentication are reported as being correct by iis. I have a personal DNS that I am using to host the site, and I have the website in IIS being hosted by that DNS. Whenever I go to browse to the site, internet explorer kicks back a page saying it could not connect to the page. It will not let me diagnose any connection problems. Any idea what could be going wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to [configure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732079%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and examine the IIS logs?

Comment: I have the logs configured. I don't have Failed logs. I do have one log, though. 

#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2012-08-08 15:12:06
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2012-08-08 15:12:06 ::1 GET / - 81 - ::1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+WOW64;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729) 403 14 0 483